# Find text within a html element and replacing it with tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to look into the text content of an element say **X** and if the html tag like `< edit>` is present in the form of `&lt edit &gt` ,it should be converted to a html edit tag.

The element **X** may be something like:

`<div><ul><li>*theEditTagInFormofText*</li></ul></div>`

Or

May not have an edit tag at all.

I can get hold of the text using `Elem.text()` or `Elem.contents()` and convert it into a html tag by adding the text to a temporary div's innerHTML.But I am facing a problem as to how to write it back to element **X**.

Here is my attempt

```
for ( var j = 0 ; j < $(elemAdded).contents().length ; j++){
     var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
     tempDiv.innerHTML = $(elemAdded).contents()[j].textContent;
      if( $(tempDiv).find("edit").length > 0){
 //      $(elemAdded).contents()[j].parentNode.innerHTML = tempDiv.innerHTML;
          formattedHTML += tempDiv.innerHTML;
  // flag = 1;
        }else{
          if($(elemAdded).contents()[j].nodeType == 3) formattedHTML += $(elemAdded).contents()[j].textContent;
           else formattedHTML += $(elemAdded).contents()[j].outerHTML;
          }
    }
   $(elemAdded).html(formattedHTML);
```

Comment: Pls add the code you've already attempted to your question.

Comment: you can give us fiddle also

Comment: I have added my attempt. Am still unable to figure out a way

Answer (score 0):

you can get the Html of that and then remove the original at the end append the new html. You can get the html using Jquery [Inner Html](https://api.jquery.com/html/)